# Japanese Corn and Mayo Pizza

Tags: japan, food-and-drink

I read about a Japanese pizza with corn and mayo. Sounds interesting! I'd like to order from a place that is popular in Japan, but that's NOT considered fancy, artisan, or gourmet. From which restaurants can I order, preferably by delivery, in either Tokyo or Kyoto? Which toppings are traditionally ordered along with the corn and mayo?

Comment: I can't believe someone would be so cruel to bake @MarkMayo into a pizza! :O

Comment: I have had corn and mayo pizza while visiting Japan. It was wonderful....simply loved it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been living in Japan for more than an year now. While I agree with the suggestion by @joe to try "Saizeriya", where you can get a decent pizza for a budget-friendly price, I would like to suggest another option that satisfy your needs.

Japan has a variety of Pizza flavors and there are food chains that offer almost all of them at a reasonable price like 'Dominos'. They have the app (English and Japanese) for both Andriod, iOS and [Website](https://www.dominos.jp/en) where delivery is possible to almost any location in Tokyo and Kyoto. 
You can also custom make your own pizza in the app/website, which would be useful if you are vegetarian. The other suggested flavors to look for are Jaga-Mayo(Potato-Mayo) on Dominos menu. The prices are decent than many other pizza chains and download/use the [Dominos coupon app](https://www.dominos.jp/en/coupon-app) for huge discounts available all year.

Cheers!

Comment: I am sure you do not intent to spam that one pizza chain. But can you tell us how you are connected to them? Just a happy customer, working for them or something else again?

Comment: @Willeke And yet even if there's a connection, it's not as if those are referral links.  They're just generic web links.

Comment: @Willeke I am just a regular customer with them as my go-to store for pizza cravings on a moody day to go along with Netflix. Hope that solves your investigation :) Happy Halloween!

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Saizeriya](https://www.saizeriya.co.jp/). It is basically a budget chain of Italian restaurants. You can find many of them in central Tokyo.

Comment: ...ehh. While Saizeriya does absolutely tick the OP's boxes of "not fancy, gourmet or artisan", everything at Saizeriya is precooked and reheated, and the one pizza I had was pretty dire.  Perhaps the good news is that after a few glasses of their ¥100 wine you don't care?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **[Shakey's Pizza](https://www.shakeys.jp/)**.  Yes, it's originally an American chain, but they're (in)famous for *deeply* localizing their offerings.  What's more, they have cheap all-you-can-eat buffets ("viking", in Japanese) for both lunch and dinner from ¥1400/person, so you can sample not just Mayonnaise Corn, but other [only-in-Japan delicacies](https://shakeys.jp/store/docs/2206EI.pdf) including:

[image]

- Potato Pizza
- Cuttlefish & Olive Pizza
- Cuttlefish, Tuna & Laver [nori seaweed] Pizza
- Chocolate & Banana Pizza
- Cinnamon Apple Pizza
- Burger Pizza [I'm not sure what this is and I'm afraid to ask]

What's more, you also get monthly specials like the three above: Spicy Rice Cakes Pizza, Rainbow Dessert Pizza and Yangnyeon Chicken Pizza.

I am, however, somewhat sad to note that my favorites the Fruit Salad Pizza (yes, from a can, with cheese on top) and the Squid & Pickled Ginger Pizza seem to be off the menu.  *Sic transit gloria pizza de Iaponia.*